# Ajax call not working in mozilla

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

My code is working fine in all the browser except mozilla firefox

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var id1 = '<%=ViewData["UserName"]%>';
            var id2 = '<%=ViewData["UsrProfile"]%>';
            var msg = $('#addFrnd').attr('value');
            $.ajax(
              {
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/Profile/SendFriendRequest",
                  data: "id=" + id1 + "&id1=" + id2 + "&message=" + msg,
                  success: function (result) {
                      $('#addLineItemControlSection').jqmHide();
                  },
                  error: function (req, status, error) {
                      alert("Make sure that javascript is enabled on your browser");
                  }
              });
        });
```

Comment: firefox has excellent debugging facilities (firebug), debugging your problem and/or providing additional information should be a breeze.

Comment: Also, you do realize that your error-code makes no sense at all. How can it complain about javascript being enabled through a javascript callback?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var id1 = '<%=ViewData["UserName"]%>';
            var id2 = '<%=ViewData["UsrProfile"]%>';
            var msg = $('#addFrnd').attr('value');
            $.ajax(
              {
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "/Profile/SendFriendRequest",
                  data: {'id': id1 , 'id1': id2,'message':msg},
                  success: function (result) {
                      $('#addLineItemControlSection').jqmHide();
                  },
                  error: function (req, status, error) {
                      alert("Make sure that javascript is enabled on your browser");
                  }
              });
        });
```

Old

```
data: "id=" + id1 + "&id1=" + id2 + "&message=" + msg,
```

New

```
data: {'id': id1 , 'id1': id2,'message':msg},
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning what the actual issue was. Otherwise everyone needs to compare you answer with the original code, line by line.